# OnDemand images are missing (http://www.flipkart.com and www.cnn.com)

Tags: qt, wkhtmltopdf, qtwebkit

I am trying to convert the below mentioned website to PDF, but the ondemand images are missing in the converted PDF. Can you please let me know, any tweaks or tricks that acquire images in the output PDF. Already i tried giving the javascript delay

http://www.cnn.com 
http://www.flipkart.com

- Command line - `wkhtmltopdf.exe http://www.cnn.com/`
  G:/test/wkhtmlcnn.pdf
- WKHTML version - wkhtmltopdf 0.12.2.1 (with patched qt)
- OS and version - Windows 8.1

[image: Wkhtml output PDF]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achieved by changing the viewport values of WkHTML option